# CALayer extension not working, Border setting black default

Tags: swift

I had used this code to set the border to views. Before Xcode 11 it was working fine and setting the color. From Xcode 11 border color setting to black.

```
extension CALayer {
    var borderUIColor: UIColor {
        set {
            self.borderColor = newValue.cgColor
        }

        get {
            return UIColor(cgColor: self.borderColor!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but for the getter, it would be safer to write `if let borderColor = self.borderColor { return UIColor(cgColor: borderColor) } else { return UIColor.black }` instead of using `!`.

Comment: `extension CGColor {`
    `var uiColor: UIColor? { UIColor(cgColor: self) }`
`}`
`extension CALayer {`
   `var borderUIColor: UIColor? {`
        `set { borderColor = newValue?.cgColor }`
        `get { borderColor?.uiColor }`
    `}`
`}`

Comment: I'm setting the border from storyboard run time attributes. Previously i used Xcode 10.2.1 then border color was showing exactly what i added(Color). Recently Updated to Xcode 11.1 then border color showing black only.